# Hopf basis of the cohomology of a Lie group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Let $M$ be a compact connected Lie group. Then by Hopf Theorem there exist uniform undecomposable elements $a_i\in H^*(M,\mathbb{Q})$ so that 
 $ H^*(M,\mathbb{Q})=\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}}(a_1.,,,.a_s)$. Let $F$ be a closed normal subgroup of $M$ and let $B=M/F$. Let 
 $a_1.,,,.a_s$ and $b_1,...,b_s$ be such bases for $H^*(F;\mathbb{Q})$ and $H^*(B;\mathbb{Q})$ respectively. How do they determine the basis for $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$?

Let us present the natural candidate. In the spectral sequence of the fibration $F\to M\to B$ we have $E_2^{pq}= H^p(B;H^q(F;\mathbb{Q}))$, hence 
 $E_2^{0q}= H^0(B;H^q(F;\mathbb{Q}))=H^q(F;\mathbb{Q})$ and  $E_2^{pq}= H^p(B;H^0(F;\mathbb{Q}))=H^p(B;\mathbb{Q})$, since $F$ and $B$ are connected.
 Now $a_1.,,,.a_s$ determine a basis in $E_2^{0*}$ and $b_1,...,b_s$ determine a basis in $E_2^{*0}$. Finally one may expect that the corresponding elements in $E^{**}_{\infty}$ and then in $H^*(M;\mathbb{Q})$ give the desired basis.

My problem is that it is not clear why the above elements determine something in $E^{**}_{\infty}$. More precisely why

each  $a_i\in E_2^{0*}$ belongs to the kernel of $ d_2: E_2^{0q}\to E_2^{2,q-1}$

and

each  $b_j\in E_2^{*0}$ does not belong to the image  of $ d_2: E_2^{0q}\to E_2^{2,q-1}$

and similarly for $d_3,d_4,...$? Perhaps the fact that the elements $a_i,b_j$ are indecomposable plays a role?

Comment: $a$'s and $b$'s have odd degree, and this is a spectral sequence of Hopf algebras.  Noting that there are no primitives or indecomposables in even degree, there is nothing that can hit b's or be hit by a's/